# danger to crash desktop by using ipython-nb slides in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, jupyter-notebook

I had an ugly experience when I tried to launch the ipython-nb presentation in ubuntu 10.04.
I could managed to see the presentation under chrome but with errors (slides where one over the other). But the worst thing was that once I restarted my pc, the genome(?) desktop was gone. I had to reinstall the entire linux.

I would like yo know if someone has experienced a similar crash under ubuntu12.04LTS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for a website (here in particular IPython slideshow) to be able to have any effect on the OS. If this happens, then it is probably due to en error somewhere else (wild guess error in graphic card that both crashed the slideshow and gnome). So more a hidden common denominator than cause/effect.

Also you should'nt need to reinstall Linux totally if something like that happen again. The gnome (?) desktop is just a package amoung other that you can reinstall. Of course you need to know a little about using the terminal and apt-get.

Comment: yeah, the thing is that in order to load ipython slides, by some reason I got erased my .Xauthority file, and that is something that I couldn't fix easily. It was cheaper just to load up all again. It was the same pathological behavior that happens when you update ubuntu and then you cannot access session in "graphic" mode. Just by means of terminal.